# Sum of rows of matrices

Tags: java, matrix

I want to make "one" row of the matrix completely true in the minimum number of movements, summing only it's rows.

(1==>true)

(0==>false)

this is an example:

```
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
```

solution expected: "2 movements" (can be: 1 and 2, 3 and 4, or 1 and 3)

this is a second example:

```
1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

solution expected: "3 movements"(rows 1-3-5)

I know that I can do this by brute force, but my question is if there is a way short to do this without having to compare all the rows?

Comment: Not sure if you can get around brute-forcing it, but you could efficiently brute-force it by interpreting the rows as bit patterns and performing XOR operations on them. Second step would probably be to start off with the rows that have the most bits set. From there, it's probably possible to design a fairly efficient algorithm.

Comment: I think that not is necessary tell it, but the operator that I use for sum rows is the common "or".
examples: 
(false || false) ==> false //
(false || true)==> true //
(true|| false) ==> true //
(true || true) ==>true

Comment: Hmmm... there are problems with both OR and XOR. `1 + 1` yields 2, but `1 | 1` yields 1. Similarly for XOR, `1 + 1 + 1` yields 3, but `1 ^ 1 ^ 1` yields 1. Unless you want `1 + 1` to just yield 1 of course, but that's not clear from your question as you're talking about the sum.